# I have to enter term type of universities I attended, but my country doesn't follow credit hour system

Tags: phd, application

I'm applying to Ph.D. programs, and the online application asks me to enter the college's term system. They write that "Term system refers to the type of hours your credits are worth, not the length of the term or how many terms a year your college offered", but the problem is that I did not have this credit-hour system in the universities I have attended, and I do not know what to fill as it is a required field. Even if I take it to mean the number of terms per year, the problem is that one college had only one term per year--which doesn't match any of the listed options (trimester, semester, quarter).

I have emailed the concerned university, but I did not receive a reply. Can someone please help me as to what I should do as I am not very aware of the American education system.

Comment: Is your country listed in this [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_term) page?

Comment: @scaaahu: Those all seem to have to do with the length of a term, which the application says it's not about.

Comment: I myself am extremely aware of the American education system, having spent 19 years as student / postdoc / faculty, and I don't have any idea what that sentence means either.  Is there any more context?  If not, I think you'll just have to wait for a reply, or if the deadline is approaching, enter something like "0" or "not applicable" and include an explanation somewhere else in the application.

Comment: The deadline is tomorrow, I was counting on the concerned university to reply. There's no option to enter anything apart from semester/ trimester/ quarter.

Comment: @NateEldredge this is the help document where the term type is defined: https://help.liaisonedu.com/BU_Graduate_School_of_Arts_and_Sciences_Applicant_Help_Center/Filling_Out_Your_BU_Graduate_School_of_Arts_and_Sciences_Application/BU_Graduate_School_of_Arts_and_Sciences_Academic_History/2_Colleges_Attended#Uploading_Transcripts

Comment: The context seems to be that you say semester if the courses on the transcript correspond to Fall/Spring semester courses - even if there's technically a summer term too. If you only have full year long courses... I'd wait it out to see if they respond, and otherwise go 'semester' as the closest thing. As they write, they will verify things later.

Comment: That sentence hardly makes sense, don't feel too bad

Comment: @AzorAhai is right: don't feel bad. The people who design forms do not know about every possible contingency. When I applied for my current PhD research position I was asked for an academic transcript. I answered I don't have one. And for two academic referees. I answered I don't have any. What mattered was not what I put, or did not put, in the form but what the decision-maker considered important. And, believe it or not, some decision-makers are both intelligent and reasonable.