# What is the equivalent degree of MPhil in the American education system?

Tags: application

I am applying to some universities for a Ph.D. degree, and I have to list all the degrees I have earned or am expected to earn. One of such degrees is Mphil. However, it is not listed in the drop-down menu of options.

There are three options that I think could fit--'Other Doctoral(not Phd)', 'Other Doctorate', and 'Other Master'. Which one would be the correct option? 'Other Master'? Since Mphil stands for master of philosophy?

Comment: I would think other Master, since a DPhil is equivalent to a PhD.

Comment: Contacting the relevant Admissions dept. would be sensible, both for this and your other question, if of course you have left yourself enough time ... See : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/120863/72855

Comment: Let me get this straight, you have a master's degree from a UK school that doesn't have a straight equivalent in the US and you need *our* help to decide between "Other Doctoral(not Phd)', 'Other Doctorate', and 'Other Master"?

Comment: The nature of an M.Phil. varies considerably between different UK universities: at some places, it's a taught course; at others, it's an exit qualification for people who abort a Ph.D. after the first year; and at others, it's a research degree in its own right.  To give a sensible answer, we'd probably need to know which university the M.Phil. came from.

Answer (score 1):

Masters in the USA are (traditionally) taught.  The concept of a master in research/Mphil is an alien concept.  There might be some programmes but I'm not aware of any.

For your application purposes just say Other Master and explain in your application letter that it was a research degree.

Comment: There are plenty of research (thesis) based masters programs.

Comment: @JonCuster  Most masters have a thesis but that doesn't make it a research degree.     A Mphil/Mres is 90-100% research.  A typical Master of Science would be mostly taught courses and a capstone project that leads to a thesis.

Comment: Who defined "typical" here?

Comment: @JonCuster is correct. Also, this is field and program specific. Some fields and programs only give maters degrees for people who fail out of PhD programs. Others, require a masters degree to enter a PhD program.

Comment: @SolarMike this is was my experience while looking for degrees in the USA:  Columbia, MIT, etc.  Do you have a different experience?

Comment: @KoenigLear So did you check if that is relevant to Europe? Or is "typical" meant to only apply to US?

Comment: @SolarMike by typical I only meant applicable to the US.  This is the context of the question.   He/She has an Mphil, which in the UK is a fulltime research degree.  It might also be the result of an incompleted Dphil/Phd.   In the US, The closest equivalent is another Master.